# Xcode 6, Swift and mock verification without exceptions

Tags: swift, ocmock

Anyone know how to verify an OCMock expect in Swift? Swift Doesn't use Exceptions so XCTest no longer includes `XCTAssertNoThrow`. Is There any other way to verify a method was called with OCMock? I noticed in OCMock the verify function checks the `expectations` array so I assume we could do `XCTAssertTrue(mock.expectations == 0)` if we had access.

Trying to figure some of these more complicated things out since there is little to no docs around XCTests in Swift

Answer (score 1):

Ok so Not a real answer but a work around for ObjC / Swift Projects.
Write an Object Wrapper that will run `[mock verify]` and return a bool.

Create an Obj-c H and M file.
In the .h

`+ (BOOL)verifyMock:(id)mock;`

In the .m

```
+ (BOOL)verifyMock:(id)mock
{
    BOOL called = YES;
    @try {
        [mock verify];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        called = NO;
    }
    @finally {
        return called;
    }
    return called;
}
```

Now add this Obj-c file to your Bridging-Header file so swift has access.

In your Swift XCTest file

`XCTAssertTrue(YourWrapperClassName.verifyMock(mock), "Method was not called")`