# Swift Mocking Class

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking

As far as I know there is no possible solution for mocking and stubbing methods in swift like we were used in objc with OCMock, Mockito, etc.

I'm aware of technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24916681/1472337). It is quite useful in some cases, but now I had a deadlock :)

I had a service layer where I had something like contracts(calling this method with this params will return that object as callback). This is one(greatly simplified) example:

```
class Bar
{
    func toData() -> NSData
    {
        return NSData()
    }
}

class Foo
{
    class func fromData(data: NSData) -> Foo
    {
        return Foo()
    }
}

class ServerManager
{
    let sharedInstance = ServerManager()

    class func send(request: NSData, response: (NSData)->())
    {
        //some networking code unrelated to the problem
        response(NSData())
    }
}

class MobileService1
{
    final class func Contract1(request: Bar, callback: (Foo) -> ())
    {
        ServerManager.send(request.toData()) { responseData in
            callback(Foo.fromData(responseData))
        }
    }
    //Contract2(...), Contract3(...), etc
}
```

Therefore somewhere in the code I had following scenario:

```
func someWhereInTheCode(someBool: Bool, someObject: Bar)
{
    if someBool
    {
        MobileService1.Contract1(someObject) { resultFoo in
            //self.Foo = resultFoo
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //MobileService1.Contract2(...)
    }
}
```

And the question now is how the heck could I test this? Is there better(for testing) alternative for code structure without touching contracts themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never I found a solution. Just make dependency injection of the `MobileService1`(or better of it's interface) and then mock it easily:

```
//declaring interface
protocol MobileServiceContracts: class {
    static func Contract1(request: Bar, callback: (Foo) -> ())
}

//make implementation to conform to interface
class MobileService1 : MobileServiceContracts
{
    final class func Contract1(request: Bar, callback: (Foo) -> ())
    {
        ServerManager.send(request.toData()) { responseData in
            callback(Foo.fromData(responseData))
        }
    }
    //Contract2(...), Contract3(...), etc
}

//inject service
func someWhereInTheCode(someBool: Bool, someObject: Bar, serviceProvider: MobileServiceContracts.Type = MobileService1.self)
{
    if someBool
    {
        serviceProvider.Contract1(someObject) { resultFoo in
            //self.Foo = resultFoo
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //MobileService1.Contract2(...)
    }
}
```

Now you can easily change service in your tests:

```
class MockedMobileService1: MobileServiceContracts
{
    static func Contract1(request: Bar, callback: (Foo) -> ()) {
        //do whatever with the mock
    }
}

someWhereInTheCode(false, someObject: Bar(), serviceProvider: MockedMobileService1.self)
```

And the best part is with default values you can still call it the old way(not braking change):

```
someWhereInTheCode(false, someObject: Bar())
```

Comment: Thus you have to change a lot on your prod code. Quite risky

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile, you can do mocking with [Cuckoo](https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo), which is similar to Mockito.

Example Classes:

```
class ExampleObject {

    var number: Int = 0

    func evaluate(number: Int) -> Bool {
        return self.number == number
    }

}

class ExampleChecker {

    func check(object: ExampleObject) -> Bool {
        return object.evaluate(5)
    }

}
```

Example Test:

```
@testable import App
import Cuckoo
import XCTest

class ExampleCheckerTests: XCTestCase {

    func testCheck() {
        // 1. Arrange
        let object = MockExampleObject().spy(on: ExampleObject())
        stub(object) { object in
            when(object.evaluate(any())).thenDoNothing()
        }
        let checker = ExampleChecker()

        // 2. Action
        checker.check(object)

        // 3. Assert
        _ = verify(object).number.get
        verify(object).evaluate(any())
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(object)
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to drag/drop generated file to XCode, how you will do it with CI/CD pipelines?

Answer (score -1):

There’s a much better framework called [Mockingbird](https://github.com/birdrides/mockingbird).

It’s super simple to setup and dynamically builds your mocks as the application builds to run the tests. [Here’s an article](https://jacobzivandesign.com/technology/mockingbird/) that explains how some of it works